# Missing hop in traceroute

Tags: networking, traceroute

I have a Ubuntu Server connected to two networks: `10.0.8.18/24` and `10.0.18.2/24`.

When doing `traceroute` from `10.0.8.x` to an IP in `10.0.18.0/24` I get:

```
traceroute to 10.0.18.1 (10.0.18.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.0.8.18 (10.0.8.18)  18.237 ms  18.217 ms  18.438 ms
 2  10.0.18.1 (10.0.18.1)  18.455 ms * *
```

But when doing the `traceroute` to the IP `10.0.18.2` I only get:

```
traceroute to 10.0.18.2 (10.0.18.2), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.0.18.2 (10.0.18.2)  17.809 ms  17.822 ms  17.818 ms
```

Is there a way to make `10.0.8.18` appear as a hop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the difference between forwarding and contacting a local IP: Linux treats all local IP addresses the same, so you can reach any local IP address directly from any interface. The packet is not somehow forwarded to the other interfaces first, and then processed.

This confuses a lot of people; you are not the first to ask.

So your traceroute correctly shows what actually happens.

And as long as that's what happens (you can reconfigure the "treat all IPs as local" behaviour, though it's not obvious if one could get your desired behaviour, and it will probably break other things, so I wouldn't recommend it), no, you cannot make the "missing" hop appear, as it's not really missing.

Comment: You can reconfigure the weird "respond to ARP queries to all IPs" behavior, but I'm not sure if you can really reconfigure the fairly standard "the entire system, not individual interface, counts as a TTL 'hop'" behavior?

Comment: @user1686 It definitely needs some trickery, and sysctl, and maybe even `iptables`, but I have one or two ideas how it could be done. I am not going to spend the time to find out though, but you are free to ask this as a question...